# Web API 2.0 not updating two new fields on SQL database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

Good Day,

I have created an android app that passes data to a Web API 2.0 web service and populates a table.

Everything works fine but since I added 2 new columns (**Barcode and AssetNo**)to the table, it does not insert these 2 values only, I get no errors and the table row inserts fine except for the two columns.

I have checked my Json sent and everything is fine, I have also updated the DataModel in my web service (the 2 new fields are showing in the data model).

My **Json**:

```
   {  
   "SerialNo":"6001007219697",
   "Manufacturer":"Unknown",
   "Model":"Unknown",
   "Brand":"Unknown",
   "Grade":"Unknown",
   "Condition":"Unknown",
   "OutletName":"hdjejjd",
   "StreetNo":"duudgdue",
   "StreetName":"duvdiebd",
   "Suburb":"dduh",
   "Town":"ddhdgd",
   "Province":"Gauteng",
   "Notes":"hdiwvud",
   "GPSLat":"Latitude: -26.11736226",
   "GPSLong":"Longitude: 28.13540941",
   "VerificationDate":"Mon Feb 18 14:05:13 GMT+02:00 2019",
   "VerificationUser":"The Bev Co",
   "Country":"South Africa",
   "Barcode:":"6001007219697 barcode",
   "AssetNo:":"6001007219697 asset no"
}
```

My Web API info:

```
    {
  "id": 1,
  "serialNo": "sample string 2",
  "manufacturer": "sample string 3",
  "model": "sample string 4",
  "brand": "sample string 5",
  "grade": "sample string 6",
  "condition": "sample string 7",
  "outletName": "sample string 8",
  "streetNo": "sample string 9",
  "streetName": "sample string 10",
  "suburb": "sample string 11",
  "town": "sample string 12",
  "province": "sample string 13",
  "notes": "sample string 14",
  "gpsLat": "sample string 15",
  "gpsLong": "sample string 16",
  "verificationDate": "sample string 17",
  "verificationUser": "sample string 18",
  "country": "sample string 19",
  "barcode": "sample string 20",
  "assetNo": "sample string 21"
}
```

Please assist.

Thank you!

Comment: To narrow down the problem write unit test that works only with EF part i.e. inserting data. Information you provided is not enough to expect the answer that will solve your problem.

Comment: I have stepped through the web api code on send and the problem is that the AssetNo and SerialNo are coming through as null. But they are present on the JSON being sent

Comment: and the model class on the web api also has those two properties?

Comment: my model class is empty, I basically created the web api from the database

Comment: I am now re-creating the entire web api from scratch, it is still in the beginning stages of development but will post a solution should I find one